# Getting closest link in NetLogo

Tags: netlogo, graph-visualization

What's the best way to get the link closest to a particular point in netlogo?

The best would be a link reporter `link-distancexy` that takes an `xcor` and `ycor` and outputs the closest distance from that point to a point on the link. Next best would just be a general reporter `closest-link-xy` that takes and `xcor` and `ycor` and reports the closest link.

This problem is complicated by wrapping boundaries, but an imperfect solutions would still be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jim Lyon's answer pointed me to the exact solution using basic triangle geometry:

```
to-report link-distance [ x y ]
  let a [ distancexy x y ] of end1
  let b [ distancexy x y ] of end2
  let c link-length
  let d (0 - a ^ 2 + b ^ 2 + c ^ 2) / (2 * c)
  if d > c [
    report a
  ]
  if d < 0 [
    report b
  ]
  report sqrt (b ^ 2 - d ^ 2)
end
```

This works for both wrapping and non-wrapping worlds.

Answer (score 4):

This function might work for your purposes. It uses the link var `both-ends` and returns the difference between the link's length and the sum of the distances from the link's two ends from a given point:

```
to-report dist [ #x #y ] ;-- by link --
  report sum [distancexy #x #y] of both-ends - link-length
end
```

Here is a short test program that shows it in action. For best results turn off wrapping:

```
to test
  clear-all
  ask n-of 12 patches [ sprout 1 [ set color red ] ]
  ask turtles [ create-links-with n-of 2 other turtles ]
end

to go  ;-- by observer, forever --
  ask links [ set color gray ]
  ask min-one-of links [dist mouse-xcor mouse-ycor] [ set color yellow ]
  display
end
```

Comment: Beautifully simple! For some reason, it didn't even occur to me to use triangle geometry. The drawbacks are that the units don't end up being in patches (not that big of a deal), and small links are penalized. But this is a great answer, and will be definitely good enough for most cases. Also, it does seem to work just as well for wrapping as non-wrapping.